# Problems with BAT file: IF/ELSE not working as expected

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a short BAT file and I'm having trouble with one of its functions. I've tried a number of different ways to do this and none of them seem to work, but being a beginner at this I can't figure out the problem. Basically, the script, as it runs, is supposed to check if a certain .BAT file exists, and if it does, the script asks if the user wants to run it. If the user indicates Y, the other BAT is called and then the original script proceeds. If the user indicates N, the script is supposed to proceed without calling the other BAT. So far the script always notices and asks about the file, but choosing Y at the prompt never works. I'm sure the solution is obvious, but it's escaping me. Here's the code:

```
SET /P kmname=Enter database name:

:kmstart

IF EXIST C:\Visual\area\%kmname%\%kmname%.flt (
        ECHO %kmname%.flt found, will now create %kmname%.ive.
        CD C:\Visual\area\%kmname%\
        IF EXIST Preprocess.bat (
            SET /P kmpreproc=Found Preprocess.bat. Do you want to run it now?
            IF /I "%kmpreproc%" EQU "Y" (
                GOTO PREPROC
            ) ELSE (
                GOTO CONTINUE
            )
        )
        GOTO CONTINUE   
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO C:\Visual\area\%kmname%\%kmname%.flt does not exist. Try again.
        SET /P kmname=Enter database name: 
        GOTO kmstart
    )
:PREPROC
ECHO Running Preprocess.bat.
:CONTINUE
ECHO Continuing process.
PAUSE
```

Comment: You need to use delayed expansion on variables you set and then use inside a code block (like an `if` or `for` block).  Add `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at the top and then use `!` instead of `%` to denote delayed variable expansion.  E.g.,  `IF /I "!kmpreproc!" EQU "Y" (`.  Don't have time to leave a more detailed answer...  Try `help set` at the command line.

Comment: Found a solution. Apparently "SET /P" doesn't work right following IF EXIST. I put the SET in its own section and made IF EXIST call a GOTO instead.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your variables are being evaluated before they enter the `if`'s, which means cmd won't see any changes until they have ended.

This is causing problems for you as your variables `kmpreproc` and, depending on the first `if` result, `kmname` change within the `if` blocks.

The fix (presuming the rest of your code is working) is to enable delayed expansion and use delayed expansion instead of normal expansion, by changing the `%`'s to `!` on your variables.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET /P kmname=Enter database name:

:kmstart

IF EXIST C:\Visual\area\!kmname!\!kmname!.flt (
        ECHO !kmname!.flt found, will now create !kmname!.ive.
        CD C:\Visual\area\!kmname!\
        IF EXIST Preprocess.bat (
            SET /P kmpreproc=Found Preprocess.bat. Do you want to run it now?
            IF /I "!kmpreproc!" EQU "Y" (
                GOTO PREPROC
            ) ELSE (
                GOTO CONTINUE
            )
        )
        GOTO CONTINUE   
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO C:\Visual\area\!kmname!\!kmname!.flt does not exist. Try again.
        SET /P kmname=Enter database name: 
        GOTO kmstart
    )
:PREPROC
ECHO Running Preprocess.bat.
:CONTINUE
ECHO Continuing process.
PAUSE
```

Comment: +1 Your explanation is confusing, but it looks like you correctly diagnosed the problem and provided a fix.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I know, I rarely leave explanations because I just can't explain things very well :) I generally only bother writing about why it works if the OP asks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is below my corrected and tided up code :

```
@echo off
SET /P kmname=Enter database name:

:kmstart

IF EXIST C:\Visual\area\%kmname%\%kmname%.flt (
        ECHO %kmname%.flt found, will now create %kmname%.ive.
        CD C:\Visual\area\%kmname%\
        IF EXIST Preprocess.bat (
            SET /P kmpreproc=Found Preprocess.bat. Do you want to run it now?
            IF /I "%kmpreproc%"=="Y" (
                GOTO PREPROC
                ) 
        GOTO CONTINUE  
        )       
)
        ECHO C:\Visual\area\%kmname%\%kmname%.flt does not exist. Try again.
        SET /P kmname=Enter database name: 
        GOTO kmstart

:PREPROC
ECHO Running Preprocess.bat.
call "cmd /c start Preprocess.bat"
pause

:CONTINUE
ECHO Continuing process.
PAUSE
```

If it doesn't work try writting `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` under `@echo off` and replacing all `%` with `!` .